# How to set divs width with flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm building a layout using flexbox with several div elements (all of them with the same height). I'd like to make them occupy either the whole width of the page or half of with, in the last case I would have two adjacent blocks, both with 50% width in order to still fill the entire width of the page.

The problem is that, when I use flexbox it seems like something overwrites the width of the blocks, and pushes them only in a row but I'd like to have them on several rows.

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

```css
.container {
  width:100vw;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.element {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
#element-1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#element-2 {
  background-color: wheat;
}
#element-3 {
  background-color: cadetBlue;
}
#element-4 {
  background-color: IndianRed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element full" id="element-1">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-2">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-3">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element full" id="element-4">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the elements to wrap by adding `flex-wrap:wrap`.

```css
.container {
  width:100vw;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.element {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
#element-1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#element-2 {
  background-color: wheat;
}
#element-3 {
  background-color: cadetBlue;
}
#element-4 {
  background-color: IndianRed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element full" id="element-1">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-2">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-3">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element full" id="element-4">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element full to always take whole width of the page, it's easier to put the out of flex container:

```
<div class="element full" id="element-1">
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element half" id="element-2">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-3">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element full" id="element-4">
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` in element class instead `display: flex;` in container class..

```css
.container {
  width:100vw;
  height: auto;
}
.element {
  height: 307px;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
#element-1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#element-2 {
  background-color: wheat;
}
#element-3 {
  background-color: cadetBlue;
}
#element-4 {
  background-color: IndianRed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element full" id="element-1">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-2">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element half" id="element-3">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="element full" id="element-4">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```